# Avoid HTTP500 and redirect user in onother url (jsp page)

Tags: jsp

i have a url like this www.myurl.jsp?param=1 
if i change manually the param=1 to an another value e.g 12 the browser gives an error page 
 An exception occurred processing JSP page /myurl.jsp  
What can i do, instead of giving this message, redirect the user to another url (that exists)
thankss!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research i find it.. to do edit the web.xml file and put these elements for a spesific error

```
<error-page>
  <error-code> 404 </error-code>
  <location>/error_404.jsp<location>
</error-page>
```

and for all the java exceptions

```
<error-page>
  <error-code> java.lang.Throwable </error-code>
  <location>/error_java.jsp<location>
</error-page>
```

and in the error_java.jsp you put

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
```